# Как хранить данные в данном случае?

Tags: java

Есть такой вот метод, который будет хранить в себе `taskи`, которые попали в определенный диапазон. Но особенность метода в том, чтобы ним могла пользоваться любая коллекция.

Кстати, я это делаю для 2-х коллекций `LinkedTaskList` и `ArrayTaskList`, которые наследуются от абстрактного класса `TaskList`, который имеет абстрактные методы `add()`, `remove()`, `getTask()`.

При этом возвращаемый тип должен быть `Iterable`.

Я не пойму какого типа сделать контейнер для хранения тасков и не понимаю чем проинициализировать `container`.

*Вопрос: каким образом это сделать?* Спасибо)

ps: Или может каким-то образом можно понять какой тип передался в параметр `Iterable<Task> tasks`

```
public static Iterable<Task> incoming(Iterable<Task> tasks, Date start, Date end) {
        Iterator i = tasks.iterator();
        ??? container = ???
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Task inext = i.next();  //for comparison
            if (inext.nextTimeAfter(start).before(end) && (inext.nextTimeAfter(start).getTime() != -1)) {
                container.add(i.next());
            }
        }
        return ???;
    }
```

Comment: У код неправильный. Два раза `next()` вызывается. И видимо во второй раз должен быть `inext`, а не `i.next()`

Comment: Зачем вам возвращать и работать именно с `Iterable<Task>`? Работайте с ваши классом `TaskList`, который возвращайте и принимайте в качестве аргумента функции. А сам класс `TaskList` должен реализовать интерфейс `Iterable`. Контейнер также будет иметь тип `TaskList`.

Answer (score 2):

Метод ничего не хранит, он в принципе ничего не может хранить, он выполняет действия над данными и может их либо вернуть, либо куда-то сохранить, сам в себе он хранить ничего не может.

[Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) - это как вам уже объясняли, интерфейс поведения, который говорит о том, что у класса реализованы соответствующие методы и его можно использовать в `for-each` циклах.

Вам видимо надо пройтись по тому что содержит переменная `tasks` и профильтровать значения, те которые попали под фильтр, вернуть как результат. Если я прав, то надо сделать так:

```
public static Iterable<Task> incoming(Iterable<Task> tasks, Date start, Date end) 
{
    List<Task> container = new ArrayList<Task>();
    for (Task inext: tasks) {
        if (inext.nextTimeAfter(start).before(end) 
                && (inext.nextTimeAfter(start).getTime() != -1)) {
            container.add(inext);
        }
    }
    return container;
}
```

**НО!** Возможно вам надо поудалять эти таски из `tasks` и вернуть этот же экземпляр класса, на это указывает сигнатура метода, очень похожая на шаблон [Строитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))([Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)). Тогда код такой:

```
public static Iterable<Task> incoming(Iterable<Task> tasks, Date start, Date end) 
{
    Iterator i = tasks.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Task inext = i.next();
        if (inext.nextTimeAfter(start).before(end) 
                && (inext.nextTimeAfter(start).getTime() != -1)) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
    return tasks;
}
```